# Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am working on "99 Ocaml Problems" and in the solution, I see this pattern matching:

```
let rec compress (mylist : 'a list) : 'a list = match mylist with
  |a::(b::_ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a::compress t
  |smaller -> smaller
```

I understand that for the first matching case, if element a is the same as element b, then I move on to the list t. If not, I will append element a to the list of compressing t.

For the second matching case, I am not sure what is the type of "smaller".

When I try to put a square bracket around it since I am thinking the author wants to match second case with one element list, but I have a non-exhaustive pattern.

Can you explain to me what the "smaller" is in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `smaller` is an `'a list`. It matches anything that doesn't match the earlier branch, i.e., a list with one element or the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the `compress` function without `smaller`:

```
   let rec compress (mylist : 'a list) : 'a list = match mylist with
    | a::(b::_ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a::compress t
    | _ -> mylist;;
```

Which says the same as the answer of user tbrk : if `mylist` does not match the first expression, then `compress mylist` returns `mylist`.